# How do I know programmatically the attributes of a file given its `Path` or `PathBuf`

Tags: rust

I want to know programmatically a file's type (whether it's an image or a text or a video, etc), its file size,etc, given its `Path` or `PathBuf`. How do I do this in rust?

Comment: There is [`std::fs::Metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html) that returns some data about the `Path`, such as the file size. However, your question is pretty broad – what exactly do you want to know about the file? Type, size and what else? And how should the file type be determined – by file content or by extension? Depending on how much information you need, it might be a better idea to split this question up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Metadata](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html) object to acquire the file size:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Acquire the object from an existing File instance 
    let metadata = std::fs::File::open("./demo").unwrap()
            .metadata().unwrap();
    
    // Or just get it directly
    let metadata = std::fs::metadata("./demo").unwrap();

    println!("Size: {}", metadata.len())
}
```

But the rest of your question is not Rust specific. There is nothing in rust, or any other language to tell you what's the file type.

A simple solution is to maintain a map `file extension -> type` but that can be fooled very easily. Just change a `.jpg` to `.txt` and it will report an incorrect type.

Another option is to read the first few bytes of the file and compare them to known `magic` numbers. For instance all PNGs start with `89 50 4e 47` in HEX, JPGs start with `ff d8 ff e0` etc.

So you can combine analyzing headers, footers, extensions and other means to truly identify the type.

Or you can use some already available crates. I've not used them, so I do not know how good and accurate they are:

- https://github.com/flier/rust-mime-sniffer
- https://docs.rs/tree_magic/0.2.3/tree_magic/

##### Update

If you only want to know if it's a text file, then you just need to read some bytes from it and try to interpret them as a string:

```rust
fn main() {
    let file = File::open("./demo").expect("failed to open file");

    let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(32);
    file.take(32)
        .read_to_end(&mut buffer)
        .expect("failed to read from file");

    match std::str::from_utf8(&buffer) {
        Ok(_) => println!("It's a text file"),
        Err(_) => println!("It's NOT a text file"),
    }
}
```

This will work for UTF-8/ASCII text files. If you want to support other encodings you have to use some additional crate that provides support for that specific code-page and basically do the same thing again.

PS: Nautilus works in the way I've explained above.

Comment: What I really would like to know is whether a file is a text file or not. For example in linux file manager(nautilus), when you check properties of a file, you see the exact type no matter its file extension.

Comment: AFAIK nautilus and most other file managers use [libmagic](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic) to determine file type from contents.